# ComboBox not showing DisplayMember

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I'm trying to display the Question ID's in the combo box, in order to reproduce the matching question in a text box. However rather than the Question ID's appearing, I am receiving this for all 5 question ID's:

> WCInterface.ucQuestions+QuestionWCInterface.ucQuestions+Question

My code:

```vb
Private loaded As Boolean = False

Private Sub ucQuestions_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    cmbQuestion.DisplayMember = "Question_ID"
    cmbQuestion.ValueMember = "Question_ID"
    cmbQuestion.DataSource = retrieveQuestions() 'when form loads

    loaded = True

End Sub

Private Sub cmbQuestion_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbQuestion.SelectedIndexChanged
    If (loaded) Then

        cmbQuestion.DisplayMember = "Question_ID"
        cmbQuestion.ValueMember = "Question_ID"
        cmbQuestion.DataSource = Nothing 'Resets data source
        cmbQuestion.DataSource = retrieveQuestions() 'when form loads
    End If
End Sub

Public Function retrieveQuestions() As List(Of Question)

    Dim typeList As New List(Of Question)
    Dim Str As String = "SELECT Question_ID, Question_Text FROM Question"
    Try
        Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(DBConnection)
            conn.Open()
            Using cmdQuery As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(Str, conn)
                Using drResult As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdQuery.ExecuteReader()
                    While drResult.Read
                        typeList.Add(New Question(drResult("Question_ID"), drResult("Question_Text")))
                    End While
                End Using 'Automatically closes connection
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("Question List Exception: " & ex.Message & vbNewLine & Str)

    End Try

    Return typeList

End Function
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions as to how I display the Question ID's, thankyou

Comment: Where is this error message appearing?

Comment: There isn't an error message, the program compiles fine. The problem is in the combo box itself, "WCInterface.ucQuestions+QuestionWCInterface.ucQuestions+Question" appears where the Question_Id's should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post your Question class, but the DisplayMember and ValueMember fields aren't matching the property fields in the Question class:

It should look something like this:

```
Public Class Question
  Property QuestionID As Integer
  Property QuestionText As String

  Public Sub New(q_ID As Integer, q_Text As String)
    QuestionID = q_ID
    QuestionText = q_Text
  End Sub
End Class
```

Then your data source properties would look like this:

```
cmbQuestion.DisplayMember = "QuestionID"
cmbQuestion.ValueMember = "QuestionID"
cmbQuestion.DataSource = retrieveQuestions()
```

Comment: Thankyou, it works now! My question class didn't match Display and Value members as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You must first assign the datasource and then assign the field to show

cmbQuestion.DataSource = Nothing 'Resets data source

cmbQuestion.DataSource = retrieveQuestions() 'when form loads

cmbQuestion.DisplayMember = "Question_ID"

cmbQuestion.ValueMember = "Question_ID"

Comment: Thankyou, I had tried this before- however I received this error on cmbQuestion.ValueMember = "Question_ID": Cannot bind to the new display member. Parameter name: newDisplayMember