# VB.Net Bind ComboBox to DataTable

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm having some trouble binding a `combobox` to a `datatable`. It appears that the query runs, but the `combobox` only displays **System.Data.DataRowView**. I've read a couple other questions about this same issue, but I haven't been able to nail down a solution yet.

```
Public Function GetSiteNames()
Dim dtSiteNames As DataTable = New DataTable("Sites")

Using con As New OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = sDbConnString
    con.Open()  'Open the connection

    Using dad As New OleDbDataAdapter(sQuery, con)
        dad.Fill(dtSiteNames)
    End Using

End Using 

Return dtSiteNames

End Function
```

I'm trying to bind this to a combobox in my main form like this:

```
    With cmboSelectSite
        .DisplayMember = "Sites"
        .ValueMember = "Sites"
        .DataSource = cQ_PLDB.GetSiteNames
    End With
```

What can I try next?

Comment: `.DisplayMember` and `.ValueMember` should be column names in the query/db

Comment: Thank you Plutonix! I knew it would be something simple! I changed "Sites" to the column name and it worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ComboBox not showing DisplayMember](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858377/combobox-not-showing-displaymember)